# Using order by VS two conditions on where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
// permlog
+----+----------+-------------+
| id | id_user  |  unix_time  |
+----+----------+-------------+
| 1  | 2353     | 1339412843  |
| 2  | 2353     | 1339412864  |
| 3  | 5462     | 1339412894  |
| 4  | 3422     | 1339412899  |
| 5  | 3422     | 1339412906  |
| 6  | 2353     | 1339412906  |
| 7  | 7785     | 1339412951  |
| 8  | 2353     | 1339413640  |
| 9  | 5462     | 1339413621  |
| 10 | 5462     | 1339414490  |
| 11 | 2353     | 1339414923  |
| 12 | 2353     | 1339419901  |
| 13 | 8007     | 1339424860  |
| 14 | 7785     | 1339424822  |
| 15 | 2353     | 1339424902  |
| 16 | 2353     | 1466272801  |
| 17 | 2353     | 1466272805  |
+----+----------+-------------+
```

I need to select last row for specific user. I have two queries:

So here is expected result:

```
/* :id = 5462 */
| 10 | 5462     | 1339414490  |
```

---

Using `order by`:

```
SELECT * FROM permlog WHERE id_user = :id ORDER BY unix_time DESC LIMIT 0, 1;
```

Using two conditions on `where` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM permlog
WHERE id_user = :id AND unix_time = ( SELECT MAX(unix_time) FROM permlog WHERE id_user = :id);
```

Which one is better? Or is there a better third option?

Comment: Depends on your indexes. BTW your second query will not work because the max `unix_time` of the table could not be the one for the specific user. And `id = unix_time` - I don't think so

Comment: I don't believe it can be the case when the second query (after it is fixed) would be at least as good as the first can potentially be (if you have proper indexes). In either case: the first optimisation rule: measure. The second optimisation rule: measure again.

Comment: @juergend Thank you .. I've edited it.

Comment: @zerkms Actually I asked this question because I read somewhere `ORDER BY` clause would be much slow.

Comment: Still `id = unix_time` will not work

Comment: "I read somewhere ORDER BY clause would be much slow" --- this statement makes no sense. There are barely absolutes in software development, especially when they are **so vague**. It is like saying: white cars are slow.

Comment: @zerkms I think the second query would actually work as he is constraining both his inner query and outer query by the user ID... so he'd only get the max unix time for a specific user, and since he's searching on that same exact user, he "should" find a max unix time on the outer query.

Comment: @dvsoukup check the question editions history. When I was posting my comment the query was different to what it is there now.

Comment: @zerkms Ahhh!  Darn edits.  Thanks for clearing that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM permlog
WHERE id_user = :id
ORDER BY unix_time DESC
LIMIT 0, 1;
```

I believe this will take advantage of an index on `permlog(id_user, unix_time desc)` (the `desc is ignored but the index should be useful).  This is better than the other approach which requires looking up values twice.

Answer (score -1):

This would get you the "last" row.  However... you should clarify what your definition of a "last" row is.  Is it the highest unix time?  The lowest unix time?  Is the last row considered an ID with the highest ID value?
Right now any answer you get would just be an assumption on what you need.

```
Select *
from permlog
where id = (select max(id)
            from permlog
            where id_user = :id)
```

Comment: The question was about which of those is "better". How would you say this is "better" than the other?

Comment: It's better because this one would perform a search based on the primary key (assuming ID is the key in this case....).  It would perform faster, though if this table is a minimal amount of data, if would be a negligible difference.

Comment: "one would perform a search based on the primary key" --- and to get a primary key value you need to perform another search with another condition. So you're doing 2 lookups here. Why do you think your nested query comes for free? If it is free - how your nested query is different from the complete solution #1 from the question? (not to say that your whole answer is based on an *assumption* that there is some correlation between the `PK` and the `unix_time` column).

Comment: Downvoting because: 1) questions about performance need much more technical answers. If you state something is "better" (faster, with less memory footprint) you need to provide some evidence to your words. For this particular case at least query plans would be sufficient. Otherwise people will think that your answer is absolute and works for every case. 2) the whole answer is simply wrong

Comment: There's actually nothing really "wrong" with the answer.  Could I have elaborated more on the technical reasons on why it would be faster?  Sure... but that doesn't make the answer flat out "wrong".  OP stated: "Which one is better? Or is there a better third option?".  I simply provided a solution for the "third option".  And I can't imagine people would think the answer is absolute for every case...  it's tailored specifically to the question here, as is the majority of all answers/questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: "Or is there a better third option?" --- your suggestion is not "better" than the solution #1 from the answer. Please prove it is the case. Please provide query plans with some decent amount of data that demonstrate that your query is evaluated more efficiently than the solution #1. "And I can't imagine people would think the answer is absolute for every case" --- simple, check the comments: OP thinks `ORDER BY` is generally slow.